# Whats wrong with this C# generic function call?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic function

```
private void PullDataAndBindGrid<T>(GridView grid, List<T> list)
{
    databaseFields = list;
    //BindGrid<T>(grid, list);
}
```

Its called like

```
private static List<FieldMaster> databaseFields;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PullDataAndBindGrid<FieldMaster>(FieldsGrid, manager.GetAddedFields());
    }
}
```

And I get compile time error as

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`'
>   to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<MailCampaign.DAL.FieldMaster>`'

Update:
The declaration of `manager.GetAddedFields()` is `public List<FieldMaster> GetAddedFields()`

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your method is generic, you cannot push any generic List type into the strongly typed databaseFields field as you are doing here:

```
databaseFields = list;
```

You should reconsider your reasons for making this method generic. If this is required then I suggest doing a check to ensure you have the right type then casting like so:

```
private static void PullDataAndBindGrid<T>(List<T> list)
{
    if (list is List<FieldMaster>)
    {
        databaseFields = list as List<FieldMaster>;    
    }       
    //BindGrid<T>(grid, list);
}
```

Comment: +1: had a resolute and unyielding need. thats why. :)  is `is` the best way to check the type of T. because i need to set different variables as per T

Comment: This is generally the preferred method. Although, if you are dealing with both inherited and base types, then you might need to use list.GetType == typeof(FieldMaster). Have a look here to see what I mean: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/10/01/779503.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is this line

```
databaseFields = list;
```

where `databaseFields` is of type `List<FieldMaster>`, and `list` is of type `List<T>`

Since you don't know what `T` will be until you actually call the function, you can't assume that something of type `List<T>` can be assigned to a variable of type `List<FieldMaster>`. Either get rid of the generics in that function, or apply generics to your entire class - either way, make sure everything is guarenteed to have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return type of the GetAddedFields() method on that manager object.